# Postgresql Function : Return table with dynamically assigned type

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a Postgresql function which execute and return table using dynamic query. below is what i'm trying now.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.function_name(tableName character varying, idValue uuid, limitValue bigint)
    RETURNS Table( -- Not sure what goes here )
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$

DECLARE 
    sqlQuery character varying;

BEGIN

sqlQuery := 'select col1,col2,col3 from ' || tableName || ' where id= ''' || idValue || ''' order by idValue asc limit '''|| limitValue ||'''';

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sqlQuery;

END

$BODY$;
```

Here table should be selected dynamically. column name of the tables are same. But it's type is different.

> eg:  Table 1: col1 character varying, col2 uuid, col3 json Table 2:
>   col1 uuid, col2 character varying, col3 character varying  etc..

Is there a way i can define the result table column type dynamically?

Comment: You can use `record`, but then you have to specify the columns when you call the function. The columns have to be known at query parse time.

Comment: I will try that, thanks @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: I have tried it, but looks like it also need the return type specified when the function is called. is there any other way? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: No; as I said, the columns have to be known at parse time.